# How to find control within ContentPlaceholder and placeholder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am adding controls dynamically to PlaceHolder which within ContentPlaceHolder

```
var t = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
var t1 = (PlaceHolder)mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("PlaceHolderName");

var t2 = (DropDownList)t1.FindControl("ControlID");
```

It looks like I am missing something because t2 is always null

Comment: Should `mpContentPlaceHolder` actually be `t`? Also, make sure you aren't adding controls in a `(!IsPostBack)` block.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to find controls of master page then you can find like :

```
Label l = Master.FindControl("label1") as Label;
```

And in your case for finding control from contentplaceholder you can find control like :

```
  TextBox TB=
  Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("textbox1") as
  TextBox;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found gridview with this method:

```
GridView gv =(GridView)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("gvRD");
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are adding controls dynamically and you are trying to find the control after postback you will not find them.

Comment: im doing it on button click and it works if Im not using ContentPlaceHolder just PlaceHolder. but I have a content pages so I need to use it

Comment: what is mpContentPlaceHolder in your code. you have assigned ContentPlaceHlder1 to variable t.  i tried something like this 'Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("PlaceHolderName").FindControl("ControlID")' and it worked without any problems.